# Quitar duplicados dejando los de mayor valor

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Tengo una tabla exportada de una bbdd de Acces a Excel, el abjetivo es quitar los duplicados pero dejar solo los que tenga el mayor valor de otra columna.

He buscado por todas partes y no encuentro de como realizarlo.
Si es con vba o con formulas de excel o SQL, de la mejor forma.

con buscarV y MAX debería funcionar pero aun así me da un error

uso la formula de MAX, como tengo excel 2016, he visto que con excel 2019 existe max.si.conjunto, pero no la tengo.
En R:R tengo las duplicadas y en AA2 creo la busqueda y en X:X están los datos a buscar el mayor.
=MAX(SI(R2:R3336=AA2;X:X))

Son muchos registros que tengo que quitar de a una.
Me podéis informar como puedo realizarlo, o una idea de como plantearlo.
Con el formulario puedo ordenarlo por, duplicada y los valores pero, ahora queda elimiarlo.
Gracias
Un saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con SQL puedes hacerlo con esto, de SO en inglés ([enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486131/select-distinct-and-max-in-the-same-query)):

```
select distinct(survey_id) as identifier, 
   (select max(survey_id) from survey) as "current" 
from survey_main;
```